# How to Customizing/add a class to the ActiveForm items with Material Bootstrap design classes on Yii2

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, bootstrap-material-design

I'm trying to add a class for a `TextField` like this one:

```
<div class="form-group-lg">

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'email'); ?>

                </div>
```

**Output:**

[image]

And that would be something like this?(the label will be inside the `TextField`).i mean, can we use it like below codes?

**Example:**

I need something like this:

```
<div class="form-group label-floating">
  <label class="control-label" for="focusedInput1">Write something to make the label float</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="focusedInput1" type="text">
</div>
```

http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/bootstrap-elements.html

> Forms section-first one.

So, the question is,

How can i add a class to this item with above codes on Yii2 ActiveForm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `fieldConfig` Propertie in `ActiveForm`.

Like as

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'id' => 'active-form',
    'fieldConfig' => [
        'template' => "<div class=\"form-group label-floating\">{label}{input}{error}</div>",
    ],
]); ?>
```

For more info read [Docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#$fieldConfig-detail)